# C code doesnt show anything on the console

Tags: c

I was trying to multiply a `double` and an `int` but it shows nothing.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double vergi = 0.01;

    int fiyat = 20;

    double sonuc = fiyat * vergi;
    
    printf("%s", sonuc);

}
```

Comment: Add `\n` after `%s` for new line and change type to double (now string): `"%lf\n"`

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings, and don't ignore them! That would probably have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` specifier is for a `String`. As per the [doc](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) says, you should use the `%f` specifier in `printf` for a `double` result.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong conversion type in printf.
You want to print variable which type is double.
This is correct - printf("%lf\n", sonuc);